# How go compare overflow int?

Tags: go, integer

When I typed like [below](https://go.dev/play/p/1nHhbPEKD2y)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64*100 > math.MaxInt64+100)
}
```

and things like `math.MaxInt64 + 100 > math.MaxInt64 + 10` and others,

it will output `true` properly, but how go compares a overflow Int64?

I know the `big` package provides some operations but is it that?

Comment: Please read https://go.dev/blog/constants. Constants do not "overflow" as constant expressions are evaluated with arbitrary precission.

Comment: @Volker thanks, I will read that post carefully.

Comment: Edit the question to show an example of the overflow you want to detect. The constant expressions in the question does not overflow as noted in the first comment.